# How to dynamically increase the height of a recyclerview as you add items to the recycler view?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, height

I would like to increase the height of the recyclerview as items are added. I have a recyclerview of phone numbers in my app, so the user can add as many numbers as he wants. But on the screen, the list only shows a contact and not that the user added. I would like it to display all your contacts added by him.

[image: print screan]

In this image, there is more than one contact, but in the view it only appears one.

Here below, follow the screen code, I'm using recyclerview inside a NestedScrollView.

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list_telefone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_ficha_telefone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_telefone" />
```

Can you help me ?

currently my screen looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONSzk.jpg

but i need it to stay like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KW9ow.jpg
(here I added a fixed height to exemplify, but I need the height to be dynamic, that is, that it increases as the user enters new phone numbers or decreases as he removes)

Comment: Having a dynamic recyclerview height is not that good in terms of the performance of recycling views

Comment: but I have a business rule that the user needs to see all the numbers he has registered in the app

Comment: you might need to add kotlin code but for java you can use list_telefone.setHasFixedSize(false); in that way when you list is updated it takes bigger or smaller space. that if i understood correctly

Comment: yep, I need the height of the list to increase as the user adds phone numbers